# JQuery .append() append PHP code

Tags: php, jquery, append

I am trying to append php to a div using

```
<script>
var values = {var1: 2, var2:"Hello"};
    $('#id').append($.get("phpfile.php", values));
</script>
```

However it doesnt seem to append the basic echo in the php file

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
echo "var1= " . $var1 . " " . "var2= " . $var2; 
?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what `$.get()` function returns?

Comment: This is not how `$.get()` works, Ajax is asynchronous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. This means that the return value of the `$.get()` function will *not* be the result of the request, as the request has not yet executed. You need to use the `$.get()` call's success handler which will be called when the request comes back successful, or make use of the jQuery deferred object (A promise) that is returned by the `$.get` function.

Correct syntax #1:

```
<script>
    var values = {var1: 2, var2:"Hello"};
    $.get("phpfile.php", values, function(data) {
        $('#id').append(data);
    });
</script>
```

Here is an alternative syntax using [promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
<script>
    var values = {var1: 2, var2:"Hello"};
    $.get("phpfile.php", values).done(function(data) {
        $('#id').append(data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added some background info, feel free to roll back if you disagree

Answer (score 0):

use this, **jQuery**:

```
<script>
    $.get("phpfile.php", { 'var1': 1, 'var2' : 2},
        function(data){ $('#id').append(data); }, "json");
    });
</script>
```

**php**:

```
<?php    
    $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
    $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
    $data = "var1= " . $var1 . " " . "var2= " . $var2;

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: This is needlessly over complicated, no need to JSON encode the output when plain output will work fine.